# Pager below sharepoint list

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, paging

I have a sharepoint site with a list, loaded from an external content type with Sharepoint designer. The list limit is 30. Below the list, a data pager is shown to navigate through the pages.

```
                             1-30 ->
```

On another list with the same limit and more than 30 items, the pager is not shown. Paging is possible only by using the task bar (List Tools -> List -> Navigate). How can I make the data pager appear?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new view on that list? Does the pager appear for that?

Comment: I have tried that now. The pager does not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the pager vas visible, but because the list was wider than the page, it showed up far to the right, so I had to scroll horizontally to find it!

Answer (score 1):

"How can I make the data pager appear?"->If the number of list items did not reach the page limit, the pager do not appear.

Actually, I couldn't understand your question. But, I guess, if u want to show the pager even list items did not reach the list limit, you can use javascript.

Comment: Yes, there are more than 30 items, see my edit.

Comment: There are two options in the list view settings, below ItemLimit property. I think you must choose the first one. I guess it must be "Show items in certain number of groups" or like this.

Comment: in both lists the first option is chosen, but only in one list is the pager.